# How can i avoid breaking the border of pages while page-break in printing the html

Tags: html, css, sass

In my project i'm having a table data displayed on the body. While printing the page its breaking in to multiple pages but the border also getting broke, as part of that the bottom border for first page and the top border for the continued pages are not coming.

I tried giving border in @media print for the each row, but in that case im getting double border

Answer (score 0):

You have to write CSS for Media Print like we are doing it for responsiveness. 
@media print {syles go here}